# Convert the EditText Text to a Hint. - Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

Well. My question is

I want to make the `EditText` text the is insereted by the user to be a hint.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried setHint(CharSequence hint) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you want to do this

```
String text = edittext.getText();
edittext.setHint(text);
```

Comment: i actually saw this method but i didnt knew what is charSequence.

Comment: A char sequence is kind of like a string, and they are usually interchangeable

Comment: @yair No problem, just click on the little check mark in the top left corner of this post to accept this answer and mark this question as solved

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
EditText editText= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
String txt= editText.getText().toString();
editText.messageText.setHint(txt);
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use android:hint in your xml...like--

```
         <EditText android:hint="Hello" />
```

set here watever hint you want to give